# Locus in $(\mathrm R ,d_{\infty})$ with $d_\infty(x,y)=\max\limits_i |x_i-y_i|$

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

> Find the locus of points $(x_1,x_2)$ in the plane such that their distance from $(1,2)$ is equal to $3$
>   at $(\mathrm R ,d_\infty(x,y)=\max\limits_i |x_i-y_i|)$

I have no idea how this is looks like.     $\quad\text{ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯}$

the only thing that I can draw is the point $(1,2)$ what is $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the boundary of the ball of radius $3$ around the point $(1,2)$. However, 'ball' does not mean circle anymore like it does when using the standard Euclidean norm. Balls in the $\ell^\infty$ norm are squares. Think about what it means to be distance one from the origin, for example. If $\max \{\lvert x_1\rvert , \lvert x_2 \rvert \} =1$, then either $\lvert x_2 \rvert \le \lvert x_1 \rvert = 1$ or $\lvert x_1 \rvert \le \lvert x_2 \rvert = 1$. In either case, one of $x_1,x_2$ has magnitude $1$ while the other has magnitude bounded by $1$. Thus you are somewhere on the square with vertices $(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,-1), (-1,1).$

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear, but I presume they ask to find the locus of points $(x_1,x_2)$ in the plane such that their distance from $(1,2)$ is equal to $3$, where the distance is not the Euclidean one but rather
$$
d=\max(|x_1-1|,|x_2-2|).
$$